# Printing the correct number of decimal number

Tags: c++

I am making a Matrix project and I make Division , I get cofactor then adjoin then Inverse to array and then multiplication with Array "matA" but the answer is like this "0.55556" and all number like this ,  how to make it only "5" to make cout for it ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,x[3][3],y[3][3];
    double c[3][3];
    int matC[3][3];

   double matA[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3},
                    {4, 5, 5},
                    {5, 5, 5},
                    };

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) //For inputting matrix
    {
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
    cout<<"Enter element number "<<i+1<<","<<j+1<<" :: ";
    cin>>x[i][j];
    }
    }

    y[0][0]=x[1][1]*x[2][2]-x[1][2]*x[2][1];                
    y[0][1]=-1*(x[1][0]*x[2][2]-x[1][2]*x[2][0]);                                                                      
    y[0][2]=x[1][0]*x[2][1]-x[1][1]*x[2][0];                                                                                
    y[1][0]=-1*(x[0][1]*x[2][2]-x[2][1]*x[0][2]);                                                                       
    y[1][1]=x[0][0]*x[2][2]-x[0][2]*x[2][0];                       
    y[1][2]=-1*(x[0][0]*x[2][1]-x[0][1]*x[2][0]);                                                                        
    y[2][0]=x[0][1]*x[1][2]-x[0][2]*x[1][1];                                                                            
    y[2][1]=-1*(x[0][0]*x[1][2]-x[0][2]*x[1][0]);                                                                     
    y[2][2]=x[0][0]*x[1][1]-x[0][1]*x[1][0];                

    long int det=x[0][0]*y[0][0]-x[0][1]*y[0][1]+x[0][2]*y[0][2];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) //For storing adjoint in another 2-D Array
    {
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    c[i][j]=y[j][i];
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) //For calculating inverse of matrix (2-D Array)
    {
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    c[i][j]=c[i][j]/det;
    }

    if(det!=0)
    {
    cout<<endl<<"\nInverse is :: ";
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    cout<<c[i][j]<<" ";

    }
    }else{
    cout<<"\nINVERSE NOT POSSIBLE AS DETERMINANT( |A| ) IS EQUAL TO ZERO";
    }


    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        matC[i][j]=0;
     for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
        matC[i][j] += (matA[i][k] * c[k][j]);
     }
     }
    }

    cout<<endl<<"\nMult is :: ";
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    cout<<matC[i][j]<<" ";

    }

    cout<<endl<<"\napproximation is :: ";
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
    if (matC[i][j] == -0 ) matC[i][j]=0;
        cout<<matC[i][j]<<" ";}
        cout<<"\n";

    }


    return 0;
    }
```

thanks to any one will help me,thanks to any one will help me thanks to any one will help me

Comment: what do you mean? print 0.55556 to 0.5 or 5 or 0.555 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the formatting in the cout. here is an example.

```
double myFloat = 1234.123456789012345;

int defaultPrecision = cout.precision(); // == 2

cout << "Default precision: " << myFloat << endl;
cout.precision(4);
cout << "Modified precision: " << myFloat << endl;
cout.setf(ios::scientific, ios::floatfield);
cout << "Modified precision & scientific format: " << myFloat << endl;
/* back to default */
cout.precision(defaultPrecision);
cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
cout << "Default precision & fixed format:  " << myFloat << endl;
```

Output for this:

```
Default precision: 1234.12
Modified precision: 1234.1235
Modified precision & scientific format: 1.2341e+03
Default precision & fixed format:  1234.12
```